# decorateTable javascript function for what it is used?

Tags: theme, javascript

In magento on cart page there is a javascript function call `decorateTable('shopping-cart-table')`. For what is used the function `decorateTable`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `decorateTable` function is used to add some classes on the `tr` and `td` elements of a table. Classes like `odd` `even` `first` `last` for the `tr` elements and `last` on the `td` elements. It's easier this way then to do it from PHP.
After adding these classes you can easily create css styles for each one of the added classes and make the table rows and columns stand out in the crowd.